# learn to run wpdb class

Tags: query, sql

I want to learn how to run commands through WP rather than SQL commands

I have a SQL command:

```
SELECT
post_id,
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key = a 'geo_latitude' AND x.post_id = a.post_id) as lat is NOT NULL,
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key = b 'geo_longitude' AND x.post_id = b.post_id) as lon is NOT NULL,
(select meta_value from wp_postmeta where meta_key = c 'address' AND x.post_id = c.post_id) as the address is NOT NULL
FROM elreal_postmeta x group by post_id, lat, lon, address
```

Can I run this command into the `wpdb` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arbitrary SQL query can be run via `wpdb` by using `get_results()` method:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( $query );
```

You can work through [documentation for `wpdb` at Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to gain basic understanding of how it works.